# What's an efficient & effective way to allocate node space for python/networkx plot?

Tags: python, plotly, networkx

Am planning a Twitter graph with node positioning by year for years 2006 through 2020. Here's the distribution:

```
{'2009': 133,
 '2012': 75,
 '2013': 71,
 '2011': 68,
 '2010': 63,
 '2008': 57,
 '2014': 27,
 '2015': 18,
 '2016': 14,
 '2007': 14,
 '2017': 10,
 '2018': 5,
 '2020': 2,
 '2019': 2,
 '2006': 1}
```

I want to graph nodes by year cluster from left to right, top to bottom [ie, 2006 in top left, 2020 in bottom right]. What's an efficient & effective way to specify position in call to 'add_node' in networkx
`Graph.add_node(node, pos=<insert desired logic here>)`?

Edit: 2020-10-10
Added this:

```
for i, node in enumerate(df['node_name']):
    pos = (0, 0)
    year_cluster = df.iloc[i]['year_cluster']
    if year_cluster == 1:
        pos = (1, 1)
    elif year_cluster in range(2, 4):
        pos = (random.randint(100, 201), random.randint(100, 201))
    elif year_cluster == 4:
        pos = (random.randint(300, 501), random.randint(300, 501))
    elif year_cluster in range(5, 9):
        pos = (random.randint(600, 901), random.randint(600, 901))
    elif year_cluster in range(9, 16):
        pos = (random.randint(1100, 1201), random.randint(1100, 1201))
    G.add_node(node, pos=pos)
```

This is my current graph [note: 560 nodes, 275 of which have 103+ edges, so yeah it's dense]

[image: plotly_graph]

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?  If so, can you show us that?

Comment: @Steve, i added. Credit @ vurmux for formatting